# System.Tuple warning on wp8 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

i have this warning on my wp8 project:

> Warning   1   The predefined type 'System.Tuple' is defined in multiple
>   assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\mscorlib.dll'
>   C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\GitHub.........\CSC

ps: ive updated the project from wp7 to wp8 on visual studio 2012, then to visual studio 2013, but the warning appeared a few days later (about 3/4)

someone can help me to find and fix this warning? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Windows Phone 8, System.Tuple is defined in .net Framework. It's also defined in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit; most probably only in the WP7 version.

Replace your current version of the Toolkit with the WP8 version, e.g. by using the NuGet manager.

If the warning is still shown, you can either ignore it or download the Toolkit's code and remove \Common\Tuple.cs.